# MySQL Order by Date, with NULL first

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a select statement that I would like to select 1 record from a table. The structure is:

```
id | start_time 
--------------
1    NULL
2    2014-08-23
3    2014-09-01
```

I would like to select the item with a NULL start time, but if that does not exist I would like it to select the latest `start_time`. I have tried using `ORDER` with `LIMIT 1`, but using `ORDER BY start_time` either gives NULL first followed by the earliest starting, or latest starting then NULL. Is it possible to have result order `1,3,2` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use two sort expressions to get the ordering you want:

```
select t.*
from table t
order by (start_time is null) desc,
         start_time desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have two different `ORDER BY` expressions:

`SELECT * from table ORDER BY (start_time IS NULL) DESC, start_time DESC;`